# How to find if a value exists within a VARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I've created a VARRAY within a table (below)
I would like to query whether or not a Title has a particular theme, eg. Show 'Action' games.
I'm not to sure how to go about this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Theme_Game AS OBJECT
(Theme VARCHAR(20));
/ 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Theme_Type AS VARRAY(3) OF Theme_Game;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT
(Title VARCHAR2(50),
GameTheme Theme_Type);
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Star Wars' ,(Theme_Type(Theme_Game('Action'), Theme_Game('FPS'))))
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the nested table in the FROM clause using the `table()` function. You can then reference attributes of the collection:

```
SQL> select g.title
  2  from game_table g
  3       , table(g.gametheme) gt
  4  where gt.theme = 'Action';

TITLE
--------------------------------------------------
Star Wars

SQL>
```

---

> "what if I then needed to retrieve rows with multiple Themes i.e Action, FPS?"

Apologies for the clunky solution but I need to go to work now. I may post a more elegant solution later.

```
SQL> select * from game_table
  2  /

TITLE
--------------------------------------------------
GAMETHEME(THEME)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Star Wars
THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Action'), THEME_GAME('FPS'))

Uncharted 3
THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Action'), THEME_GAME('Puzzle'))

Commander Cody
THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Fun'), THEME_GAME('Puzzle'))


SQL> select g.title
  2  from game_table g
  3       , table(g.gametheme) gt
  4       , table(g.gametheme) gt1
  5  where gt.theme = 'Action'
  6  and gt1.theme = 'FPS' ;

TITLE
--------------------------------------------------
Star Wars

SQL>
```

---

This alternative approach won't work with your current type because VARRAY does not support `member of`. But it would work if the collection was a Nested Table.

```
 select g.title
  from game_table g
  where  'Action' member of g.gametheme
  and 'FPS' member of g.gametheme
```

Comment: This statement works, however what if I then needed to retrieve rows with multiple Themes i.e Action, FPS?

Comment: @APC OR will not help if he needs titles having both themes. Use `intersect` then.

Comment: I've tried to use an 'AND' in this case I'm trying to retrieve rows that are both Action and FPS but it doesn't return any rows.

Comment: @RadimBača Thank you, that's what I meant sorry for not being clear with my question APC.

Comment: Sorry to sound amateur but I've tried using a !=, <>, WHERE NOT, NOT LIKE clauses but it still returns Star Wars..

Answer (score 0):

For multiple themes you could do something like

```
select g.Title
from game_table g, table(g.gameTheme) t
where t.Theme in ('FPS','Action')
group by g.Title having count(0) = 2;
```

This could also allow you to do things like get titles with exactly n matches, at least n matches, at most n matches...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection and then compare multiple items using the `SUBMULTISET` operator:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2a89/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Theme_Game AS OBJECT
(Theme VARCHAR(20));
/ 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Theme_Type AS TABLE OF Theme_Game;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT(
  Title VARCHAR2(50),
  GameTheme Theme_Type
);
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
NESTED TABLE GameTheme STORE AS GameTheme_Tab
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Star Wars' ,(Theme_Type(Theme_Game('Action'), Theme_Game('FPS'))))
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table
WHERE  Theme_Type(Theme_Game('Action'), Theme_Game('FPS'))
       SUBMULTISET OF GameTheme
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d2a89/2/0)**:

```
|     TITLE |                                             GAMETHEME |
|-----------|-------------------------------------------------------|
| Star Wars | oracle.sql.STRUCT@67e8dc0f,oracle.sql.STRUCT@795b6d4c |
```

However, why are you using the `Theme_Game` object when it only has a single `VARCHAR2` attribute? You can just use a `VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20)` or `TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)` without the intermediate object:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c68a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Varchar20List AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT(
  Title VARCHAR2(50),
  GameTheme Varchar20List
);
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
NESTED TABLE GameTheme STORE AS GameTheme_Tab
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Star Wars' , Varchar20List('Action', 'FPS'))
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table
WHERE  Varchar20List('Action','FPS')
       SUBMULTISET OF GameTheme
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c68a/1/0)**:

```
|     TITLE |  GAMETHEME |
|-----------|------------|
| Star Wars | Action,FPS |
```

If you want to do it with `VARRAY`s then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0342/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Varchar20List AS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT(
  Title VARCHAR2(50),
  GameTheme Varchar20List
);
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Star Wars' , Varchar20List('Action', 'FPS'))
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table g
WHERE  2 >= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM   TABLE( g.GameTheme ) a
                     INNER JOIN
                     TABLE( Varchar20List( 'Action', 'FPS' ) ) b
                     ON ( a.COLUMN_VALUE = b.COLUMN_VALUE )
             )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0342/3/0)**:

```
|     TITLE |  GAMETHEME |
|-----------|------------|
| Star Wars | Action,FPS |
```

or:

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table g
WHERE  2 >= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM   TABLE( g.GameTheme ) a
              WHERE  a.COLUMN_VALUE IN ( 'Action', 'FPS' )
             )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0342/3/1)**:

```
|     TITLE |  GAMETHEME |
|-----------|------------|
| Star Wars | Action,FPS |
```