# Output VARRAY results into 1 row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've been stumped on this for a while now.
I'm trying to retrieve the values within a VARRAY and query it into the same row under another value, in this case the Title of the game, please see below for more info. The tables are currently like this (I've taken a lot of attributes out to simplify it)

```
CREATE TYPE Publisher_Type AS OBJECT
(PublisherName VARCHAR2(30))
/
CREATE TABLE Publisher_Table of Publisher_Type
/
INSERT INTO Publisher_Table
VALUES ('EA')
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Genre_Game AS OBJECT
(Genre VARCHAR(20))
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Genre_Type AS VARRAY(3) OF Genre_Game
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT
(Title VARCHAR2(50),
GamePublisher REF Publisher_Type
GameGenre Genre_Type)
/
CREATE Game_Table of Game_Type
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Madden 17', (SELECT REF(c) FROM Publisher_Table WHERE 
c.PublisherName = 'EA'), (Genre_Type(Genre_Game('Sports'), 
Genre_Game('Simulation'), Genre_Game('Football')))
```

The below is what I've tried from reading some posts online but it just won't work. My ideal output is 
    **Madden 17      EA      Sports, Simulation, Football**

```
SELECT title , m.GamePublisher.PublisherName,
max( decode( rn, 1, GameGenre ) ) genre1,
max( decode( rn, 2, GameGenre ) ) genre2,
max( decode( rn, 3, GameGenre ) ) genre3
FROM (
SELECT title, m.GamePublisher.PublisherName, f.*,
row_number() over (partition by title order by GameGenre) rn
FROM Game_Table m, table(m.GameGenre) f
WHERE title = 'Madden 17'
)
group by title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use LISTAGG() to concatenate the theme values, grouped by the Game level columns. I'm using the data from [this apparently related question I answered yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46681631/146325).

```
SQL> select title
  2         , listagg(gt.theme, ',') within group (order by gt.theme) as themes
  3  from game_table
  4      , table(gametheme) gt
  5  group by title;

TITLE                THEMES
-------------------- -------------------------
Commander Cody       Fun,Puzzle
Star Wars            Action,FPS
Uncharted 3          Action,Puzzle
```

SQL>