# Return row if value NOT EXISTS within a row VARRAY

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get a query to return a Book *only* if it doesn't contain a particular genre this case being a romance novel. The genre data is being inserted as a VARRAY of Genre_Type which contains only a 'Genre' attribute. The below is how the example data has been inserted.

```
INSERT INTO Book_Table
VALUES(1, 'Assassin's Quest', 'A young boy is trained by his King to do his bidding', 
(Genre_Type(Genre_Book('Adventure'), Genre_Book('Drama'), 
Genre_Book('Fantasy'))))
```

The below query is returning NO ROWS SELECTED because I presume it will return nothing if *another* book has 'Romance' as one of the Genres.

```
SELECT Title
FROM Book_Table
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT g.* 
FROM Book_Table k, table(k.BookGenre) g
WHERE g.Genre = 'Romance')
```

How do I get around this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Book_Table` have ID? 
Can you try query like this:

```
SELECT bt1.Title
FROM Book_Table bt1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT g.* 
FROM Book_Table k, table(k.BookGenre) g
WHERE g.Genre = 'Romance' and k.id = bt1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: this is [like your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46681631/146325) in that the choice of a VARRAY over a Nested Table forces you into clunky syntax. With a Nested Table you could use the much more elegant NOT MEMBER OF.

```
SQL> select *
  2  from game_table g
  3  where theme_game('FPS') not member of g.gametheme;

TITLE                 GAMETHEME(THEME)
--------------------  -----------------------------------------
Uncharted 3           THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Action'), THEME_GAME('Puzzle'))
Commander Cody         THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Fun'), THEME_GAME('Puzzle'))

SQL> select *
  2  from game_table g
  3  where theme_game('Puzzle') not member of g.gametheme;

TITLE                 GAMETHEME(THEME)
--------------------  -----------------------------------------
Star Wars             THEME_TYPE(THEME_GAME('Action'), THEME_GAME('FPS'))

SQL>
```

The only advantage of the VARRAY over a Nested Table is that the order of a VARRAY is guaranteed: the first element added to VA will always have an index of `VA(1)`, the nth element will always have an index of `VA(n)`. Unless you need that ordering capability the increased flexibility and support for additional operators make Nested Tables the better choice.