# Finding if 2 varrays have similar values

Tags: sql, oracle

just following up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680792/how-to-find-if-a-value-exists-within-a-varray), I'm wondering how I can retrieve rows where there are similar values, that is if 2 games had 2 or more common themes.

After some digging online, I figured the query below was as close as I can get.. but it obviously doesn't work. The comments in my previous question may work if I specify the themes I'm looking for.

```
select title
from (select c.*, count(table(c.gametheme)) over (partition by 
table(c.gametheme)) as theme_count
from game_table c)
WHERE theme_count > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a collection rather than a `VARRAY` then you are not limited to the number of themes you can store and you can use the `MULTISET INTERSECT [ALL|DISTINCT]` operator and the `CARDINALITY` function:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f72a/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Varchar20List AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20)
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT(
  Title VARCHAR2(50),
  GameTheme Varchar20List
)
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
NESTED TABLE GameTheme STORE AS GameTheme_tab
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game A' , Varchar20List( 'Action', 'FPS') )
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game B' , Varchar20List( 'Action', 'FPS', 'P2W') )
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game C' , Varchar20List( 'FPS', 'P2W' ) )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table a
       INNER JOIN
       game_table b
       ON (
         a.title < b.title
         AND
         CARDINALITY( a.GameTheme MULTISET INTERSECT b.GameTheme ) > 1
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f72a/1/0)**:

```
|  TITLE |      GAMETHEME |  TITLE |      GAMETHEME |
|--------|----------------|--------|----------------|
| Game A |     Action,FPS | Game B | Action,FPS,P2W |
| Game B | Action,FPS,P2W | Game C |        FPS,P2W |
```

If you want to do it using `VARRAY`s then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e87ca/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Varchar20List AS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(20)
/ 

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Game_Type AS OBJECT(
  Title VARCHAR2(50),
  GameTheme Varchar20List
)
/
CREATE TABLE Game_Table of Game_Type
--NESTED TABLE GameTheme STORE AS GameTheme_tab
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game A' , Varchar20List( 'Action', 'FPS') )
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game B' , Varchar20List( 'Action', 'FPS', 'P2W') )
/
INSERT INTO Game_Table
VALUES('Game C' , Varchar20List( 'FPS', 'P2W' ) )
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   game_table a
       INNER JOIN
       game_table b
       ON (
         a.title < b.title
         AND
         2 <= ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM   TABLE( a.GameTheme ) ag
                       INNER JOIN TABLE( b.GameTheme ) bg
                       ON ( ag.COLUMN_VALUE = bg.COLUMN_VALUE ) )
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e87ca/4/0)**:

```
|  TITLE |      GAMETHEME |  TITLE |      GAMETHEME |
|--------|----------------|--------|----------------|
| Game A |     Action,FPS | Game B | Action,FPS,P2W |
| Game B | Action,FPS,P2W | Game C |        FPS,P2W |
```